# How to execute shell command in python?

Tags: python

Code snippets are as follows:

```
import os
a= "\\"

path=r"C:"+a+"Windows"+a+"System32"

print "\n path :",path

os.chdir('C:')

os.path.abspath(path)

os.chdir(path)

print os.getcwd()

os.system('PNPUTIL.exe')
```

Result :

```
path : C:\Windows\System32

C:\Windows\System32

'PNPUTIL.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Though the utility is available its not geting identified,wat could be the problem?

Comment: Did you mean: `path = os.path.abspath(path)`?

Comment: I find it interesting that you are importing `os` but not using it to construct your path.  `a='\\' == os.sep`, and `path=r"C:"+a+"Windows"+a+"System32" == path=os.path.join("C:","Windows", "System32")`

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\\Windows\\System32\\PNPUTIL.exe'])
```

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary This one should work as well. Just tried it with `subprocess.call(['C:\\Windows\\System32\\systeminfo.exe'])`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I'm not a python expert, just do bits of it. I will check and update.

Comment: @Krishnanunni This looks fine, I guess I misread it.(cmd's commands confuse me). +1 anyway

Comment: subprocess.call(['C:\Windows\System32\PNPUTIL.exe']) also didn't work,It throws error  "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\InstallUninstall\new.py", line 8, in <module>
    subprocess.call(['C:\Windows\System32\PNPUTIL.exe'])
  File "C:\Python31\lib\subprocess.py", line 428, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python31\lib\subprocess.py", line 658, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python31\lib\subprocess.py", line 868, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: check system32 folder, find the  file 'PnPutils.exe'. Try using the case properly as in file name.

Comment: There's something weird about how windows handles PnPutil.exe because I'm having the same issue, but don't have an issue with any other subprocesses spawned.  I'm currently investigating this further.

Comment: For those of you having problems with PnPutil.exe, are you running on 64-bit windows?  I had the same problem.  You have to use C:\Windows\SYSNATIVE.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7034702/100955